# Query: adding additional operator changes meaning of preceding operators

Tags: dataset, query

Consider the following query:

```
Range[5] // Query[Select[EvenQ] /* Append[1], f]

(* {f[2], f[4], 1} *)
```

It selects the even numbers, applies `f` to them and finally appends `1` to the list.  As expected, the application of `f` occurs between the descending operator `Select` and the ascending operator `Append`.

But watch what happens if we add a `Sort` operator in an attempt to sort the final result:

```
Range[5] // Query[Select[EvenQ] /* Append[1] /* Sort, f]

(* {1} *)
```

That's a surprise!  Why didn't we get the sorted list `{1, f[2], f[4]}`?

This behaviour occurs in *Mathematica* version 11.0.1 and all previous versions back to 10.0.0.

Comment: I don't sure I have understood your question.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is a corner case that occurs when ascending operators are interleaved between descending operators.  This case falls into an undocumented grey area.

In the *Details and Options* section of the [Query](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html) documentation, we read the following special rule:

> When one or more descending operators are composed with one or more ascending operators (e.g. *desc* /* *asc*), the descending part will be applied, then subsequent operators will be applied to deeper levels, and lastly the ascending part will be applied to the result.

The statement appears to apply to the case at hand.  But appearances can be deceiving.  Consider:

```
Dataset;

Dataset`DescendingQ[Select[EvenQ]]    (* True  *)
Dataset`DescendingQ[Append[1]]        (* False *)
Dataset`DescendingQ[Sort]             (* True  *)
```

This means that the operator `Select[EvenQ] /* Append[1] /* Sort` has the form `desc /* asc /* desc`, with descending and ascending elements interleaved.

The documentation (weakly!) suggests that it only applies when all the descending operators precede all of the ascending operators.  Since our ascending operator is sandwiched between two descending operators, the special rule is not applicable.

We can make the special rule apply by replacing the descending operator `Sort` with the ascending operator `Query[Sort]`:

```
Dataset`DescendingQ[Query[Sort]]
(* False *)

Range[5] // Query[Select[EvenQ] /* Append[1] /* Query[Sort], f]
(* {1, f[2], f[4]} *)
```

This is the result we seek.

**Commentary**

Since the special rule is inapplicable, how are the interleaved operators interpreted?  The documentation is silent, but apparently the resulting composition is treated as a single ascending operator.  Thus, when a descending operator follows an ascending operator then *all* the descending operators lose their special status -- even the ones that precede the ascending operator.

This explains the result we see:

```
Range[5] // Query[Select[EvenQ] /* Append[1] /* Sort, f]

(* {1} *)
```

Since the level one operator is being treated as ascending in its entirety, it is applied after `f`.  Therefore, `Select[EvenQ]` returns nothing since none of the elements `{f[1], f[2], ...}` are `EvenQ`.  `Append[1]` acts upon an empty list, and the single element result is left unchanged by `Sort`.

Notwithstanding the documentation being silent on the matter, I am tempted to call this behaviour a bug.  At the very least, I feel the operator composition rules would be simpler if *leading* descending operators always maintained their special status.  It stands to reason that any descending operators that *follow* an ascending operator lose that status.

But until and unless the rules are ever changed like this, we must keep an eye out for this very subtle case.

**Hackery**

If we want to try out the revised rule to see how it feels, we can hack the V11.0.1 definition:

```
BeginPackage["Dataset`Query`PackagePrivate`", {"Dataset`"}]

comp[ops:RightComposition[Longest[desc__ ? VectorDescendingQ], asc__]] :=
  vectorDescendingOp[RightComposition[desc]] /* chainedOp[RightComposition[asc]];

comp[ops:RightComposition[desc___ ? VectorDescendingQ, descScalar_ ? ScalarDescendingQ, asc__]] :=
  scalarDescendingOp[desc /* descScalar] /* chainedOp[RightComposition[asc]];

EndPackage[]
```

so then:

```
Range[5] // Query[Select[EvenQ] /* Append[1] /* Sort, f]

(* {1, f[2], f[4]} *)
```

Naturally, this hack is unsanctioned and brittle.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why the `RightComposition` don't work here,but the `Composition` will give a result as we expected.

```
Range[5] // Query[Select[EvenQ] /* Sort@*Append[1], f]
```

> {1, f[2], f[4]}

Comment: This form works because `@*` has higher precedence than `/*`.  So `RightComposition` sees two terms: `Select[EvenQ]` and `Sort@*Append[1]`.  Any operator involving `@*` is always treated as ascending, so these two terms conform to the pattern _descending /* ascending_ which is documented to work.